# Sniffing SSL/TLS connections with BURP

Tags: data-monitoring, proxy, certificates, magisk

I want to sniff SSL/TLS encrypted traffic of my installed apps using BURP. 
After installing the burp certificate on my One Plus 5T and moving certificates through the Magisk tweak "Move Certificates" there are still applications like mcdonalds that I can't sniff because tell me there isn't Internet connections. I'm sure that Internet connections there is because another app like deliveroo work perfectly with burp.

I was wondering if there was a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a rooted device with Magisk it is IMHO much simpler to just disable SSL/TLS certificate checking and pinning for traffic sniffing:

- Enable Zygisk mode in Magisk
- Install LSPosed for Magisk (Zygisk)
- Install the Xposed module [Trust me already](https://github.com/ViRb3/TrustMeAlready)
- Open LSPosed app and configure Trust me already module: enable it for all apps you want to intercept traffic (system apps are hidden by default in LSPosed, you have to make them visible using the tree dots menu)