# How do I trust a certificate on android 11 device?

Tags: proxy, certificates, https

I want to setup this app called Http Toolkit and for some reason I have the warning "System Trust Disabled". My android 11 device is rooted using ksu . How do I trust a certificate on android device?
[image: ss]

[image: ss2]

Comment: You need a rooted device or you have to modify the app. Which app do you want to intercept traffic of?

Comment: One solution on a rooted device: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210140/2241 A more extensive description you can find in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978